# Excel macro : search a cell then write formulas

Tags: excel, vba

I want VBA macro code on excel to do the following:

for example i have column "C" that contains some cells with value and what else is empty
so , i want by macro , select column "C" , then looking to cells with value , then:

for each cell with value , I want to write formula to each cell located in column F,H,J : and row number depends on "that cell with value"

i spent a lot of time to find something similar but nothing helping me ..

Comment: record a macro! show your code... `I spent a lot of time to find something similar` is a complete BS. Look at the top of page where its says `search` inside a text box and type in your question... you will be amazed by the amount of the similar questions you will find. good luck

Comment: Dear Mehow,

I ment spent time on internet searching about this case but i can't find something matches.
I want to explain my case again:

I have column "C" contains these cells with these values "LT, Item , No. , Meter" 
I got cell "C23" contains "Item" , then I want to write formula to Cell "D23" and Cell "E23" .. 
I have thousands of rows to do same thing , note that there are empty cells in column "C" ..

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Row As Range

For Each Row In Me.Range("C1:J1000").Rows

    If Not Row.Range("A1").Value = "" Then

        Row.Range("D1").Formula = "SomeFormula"

        Row.Range("F1").Formula = "SomeFormula"

        Row.Range("H1").Formula = "SomeFormula"

    End If

Next
```